# Image is not displayed correctly when user clicks on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random, append

***Functionality:***

In page A, user needs to answer a question with 4 options. When user clicks on any 1 option, the current page will navigate the user to Page B where, an image will be displayed depending on the option that the user has chosen.

Therefore, this is the general flow:

Page A: 1 randomly generated question and 4 associated options to the question will be displayed -> user clicks on one of the option -> page A will navigate to page B. In page B, an image will be displayed depending on the option that you have selected in Page A.

***What I have done:***

I have created 3 arrays:

**FOR Randomly Generated Questions:**

```
var QuestionOrder = ["What is A?", "What is B?", "What is C?"];
```

**FOR 4 options to the question shown:**

```
var ChoiceOrder = [["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"], ["test5", "test6", "test7", "test8"], ["test9", "test10", "test11", "test12"]];
```

**Image to be shown in Page B depending on option selected in Page A:**

```
var DescriptionOrder = [["testA1.png", "testA2.png", "testA3.png", "testA4.png"], ["testB1.png", "testB2.png", "testB3.png", "testB4.png"], ["testC1.png", "testC2.png", "testC3.png", "testC4.png"]];
```

Therefore, when user clicks on "test1", it should display ->"testA1.png" or  when user clicks on "test12", it should display ->"testC4.png" or  when user clicks on "test8", it should display ->"testB4.png" etc...

***Code:***

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/5zDNeNG97WrTrhegMYEr?p=catalogue

***Issue:***

I am currently able to display the image element from the array var DescriptionOrder after the user has selected from Page A.

However, the issue that I am currently facing is this:

***The wrong behaviour:***

when I clicked on "test1", it is not displaying  ->"testA1.png"  but displaying -"testB4.png" or when user clicks on "test12", it is not displaying  ->"testC4.png" but displaying -"testA2.png" or when user clicks on "test8", it is not displaying   ->"testB4.png" but displaying -"testC2.png"etc...

***The correct behaviour:***

Therefore, when user clicks on "test1", it should display ->"testA1.png" or  when user clicks on "test12", it should display ->"testC4.png" or  when user clicks on "test8", it should display ->"testB4.png" etc...

Meaning, it looks like the array var DescriptionOrder is randomised and not associated based on the inner indices of the array.

What have i done wrong?? I need some help pls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line doesn't make sense:

```
printOptionFrame = DescriptionOrder[optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag - 1])][optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag - 1])];
```

It should be something like this:

```
printOptionFrame = DescriptionOrder[random_Question][optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag - 1])];
```

With your current code you are always trying to access positions like [2][2], [1][1], [0][0]. As you can see the first index should be the the randomly chosen question index.

Comment: So what you are saying is that i am always having a fix inner index reference for the option that inhave selected?? As in if i were to select the 1st option, it will call on the 1st inner index? Am i right to say that? Still a lil confuse on this. Do you mind explaining with a lil more clarity? Thanks

Comment: I didn't run the code, but as I see it, you have a matrix, formed by a list of possible answers for possible questions. If you select randomly a question, you should stick to the selected question in order all images and possible responses are shown accordingly to that question. As I say, I didn't run it so I might be wrong, but that is what I understood from your code. I don't understand why you use the same index for row and for col, that will result in you running across a diagonal over the matrix

Comment: In fact, you don't need to do this: optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag - 1]). If you are trying to get the index of the flag - 1 position you can tell that index is flag - 1, so I think it would be enough with this: printOptionFrame = DescriptionOrder[random_Question][flag - 1];